# when a shifting operation is applied on any number .how to get back the original number

Tags: c++, shift

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<stdio.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
     int n=99;
     int shift=n>>2;
     cout<<shift;
     shift=shift<<2;
     cout<<shift;
 }
```

The above result gives "unsignedShift=24". The question is if 24 is given how can I get back the original value ie `n` is 99. When I use left shift the ans it is showing is 96. How to do it for negative numbers

Comment: You can't, shifting (an int, at least) to the right is a lossy operation.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Actually, any shifting is an operation that induces data loss if valuable bits are shifted out of the variable. It doesn't matter if it is a left- or right shift. It's just a matter of the magnitude of shifting: shifting enough bits, you'll eventually start losing either MS bits or LS bits respectively.

Comment: @Powerslave not really. Shifting to the left too much results in undefined behavior (not just information loss) for signed types (as is the case here).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It does, still it's pretty much a data loss. BTW I wonder why C++ performs very poorly in this area as signed shifting either has well documented hardware support or is straightforward to emulate.

Comment: @Powerslave: It has well-documented support on most processors, but not on all, and not the same behaviour on all processors; hence, undefined behaviour. Emulation of some canonical behavoiur could be significantly slower than the single instruction (or even less) that most processors require.

Answer (score 2):

No way without storing the original number(or its part(actually last bits)) because shift isn't [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) i.e there are some different numbers that after shifting become the same.

```
3>>1 // = 1;
2>>1 // = 1;
```

If you have 1. What you're going to get? 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

Shfiting a binary represented number is effectively dividing by 2.

You are doing:

`99 / 2 * 2 = 24.75` .75 part cannot be in an `int` type so left with 24

`24 * 2 * 2 = 96`

In binary:

`1100011 = 99`

Shift by two to right:

`0011000 = 24`

Shift by two to left:

`1100000 = 96`

You've lost the lower two bits that totalled 3. Hence the difference in the results: 99 - 96 = 3.

The real question here is why you are doing this at all - you probably don't want to be doing bit manipulation operations. For working with real numbers use a `double` or similar type.

Answer (score 0):

When you did a right shift by 2 you lost the last 2 bits..again when you left shift they were replaced by 00

You can do this

keep the 2 bits as

bits_to_be_lost = n & ((0x1<<2) - 1)

then your code

to retrieve it has to be

n<<2 | bits_to_be_lost